# setInterval unusual behaviour

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the following code. Here i used a `setInterval` function and supposed it to increase the value of age by 1 every 2 seconds. But it is increasing age value in unusual way. like.. 21 23 29 ....

What wrong with my code or concept.

```
class First extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            age: 21
        }
    }

    handleEvent = () => {
        let val = this.state.age
        val++
        this.setState({age: val})
    }

    render() {
        setInterval(this.handleEvent, 2000)
        return (
            <div>
                <button>{this.state.age}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move setInterval call to constructor :)

Comment: You're adding an interval on **each** render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `setInterval` in `componentDidMount` and clear it in `componentWillUnmount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.handleEvent, 2000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure `setInterval` is only called once! The easiest way is to move it inside the `constructor`.

Also, instead off creating the temporary `val` variable, we can just use `this.state.age + 1`:

Example:

```js
class First extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            age: 21
        }
        setInterval(this.handleEvent, 2000);
    }

    handleEvent = () => {
        this.setState({age: this.state.age + 1});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>{this.state.age}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<First />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using componentDidMount for your sideEffects
Render gets called on each state update.

```
class First extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: 21
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.handleEvent, 2000);
  }

  handleEvent = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ age: state.age + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button>{this.state.age}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```